# CSS not working, trying to get li and trash icon on the same row next to each other

Tags: css

I am trying to have my delete icon inline with the li but when I use inline-block nothing changes. I also tried to set text decoration to none so there are no bullet points on the li but that didn't do anything either. I don't understand why my css isn't working. Please help!

```
  <div id="menu">
    <h1>{{menu.menu_event}} Menu:</h1>
    <ul id='itemList'>
        {% for item in menu.menu_items %}
        <a href="/menus/{{menu.menu_id}}/recipe/{{item.item_id}}"><li id='itemName'>{{item.item_name}}</li></a>
        <form id='item' action="/menus/{{menu.menu_id}}/{{item.item_id}}" method="POST">
          <i id='trash' class="far fa-trash-alt" style="color: red;"></i>
        </form>
        {%endfor%}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#menu {
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#item {
    display: inline-block;
}

#itemName {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Try setting inline instead of inline-block? Or maybe make the form inline

Comment: Could you remove 3rd languages such as `{{}}`, `{%%}`. It's diffcult to test.

Comment: And also, I'll thanks if you add snippet please

Comment: Add `list-style: none;` to `#itemName`

Answer (score 0):

:)

```css
#menu {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#item {
  display: inline-block;
}

#itemName {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <h1>Menu:</h1>
  <ul id='itemList'>

    <a href="/menus/">
      <li id='itemName'>fdfdfd</li>
    </a>
    <form id='item' action="/menus/" method="POST">
      <i id='trash' class="far fa-trash-alt" style="color: red;"></i>
    </form>
  </ul>
</div>
```